# I java I want to replace all whitespace characters with a single whitespace while maintaining all new line and carriage return characters

Tags: java, regex

So I have been trial and erroring this for a while to no avail. I've looked at the other answers here, but the only show how to get rid of all the excess, but no mention on how to preserve. The following was my last attempt:

```
records.replaceAll("\\s[^\\r^\\n]+", " ")
```

Hopefully one of you can help.

Comment: `records.replaceAll(" +", " ");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for

```
records = records.replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+"," ")
```

Thanks to [intersection operator `&&`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) we are creating character class which intersects any of whitespaces characters `\s` with characters which are not `\r` or `\n`.

Demo:

```
System.out.println("----BEFORE:");
String records = "foo    bar   baz\rABC\nDEF\t\tGHI";
System.out.println(records);
records = records.replaceAll("[\\s&&[^\r\n]]+", " ");
System.out.println("----AFTER:");
System.out.println(records);
```

Output:

```
----BEFORE:
foo    bar   baz
ABC
DEF     GHI
----AFTER:
foo bar baz
ABC
DEF GHI
```

Comment: @vks regex engine accepts any character from string, and string in Java allows us to write carriage return as `\r`. Regex also allows us to write it as `\\r` but I don't like it because it may confuse others to think it is some kind of character class like `\\s`.

Comment: in python `\r` will be `1` byte .to make it understandable for regex we do `\\r`.So i was wondering `\r` should be `\\r`

Comment: Saved my life @Pshemo!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do

```
records.replaceAll(" +", " ")
```

or

```
records.replaceAll("(?:(?!\\r|\\n)\\s)+", " ")
```